# How to translate or transform a general Polygon with arcs or holes in CGAL

Tags: transform, cgal

How to translate a general Polygon with arcs or holes in CGAL，I  writed code by iterator each X_monotone_curve_2 ,by transform it's support circle or line. and use CGAL::to_double() convert traits::point to kennel point,than transform the source and target. At end,i clear original polyset_2 contains polygon_with_hole,and then reinsert transformed polygon_with_hole, It compiled well,but throw a runtime precoord exception during the ending reinsert processing,why and who know how deal with it?

I hope someone can give me an advise